# Custom Highlight API causing significant slowdowns with large amounts of nodes

Tags: javascript, html

I noticed a strange bug (or a shortcoming) of the JavaScript Range API. Once attached, the [range object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) cannot be released manually in any way. There is a `detach()` method, but according to the docs it does nothing and is left for compatibility.

The issue becomes apparent when you try attaching large quantities of ranges to nodes (easily observable on 10000+ nodes). Subsequent removals of any node from the DOM suffer from more than 50% increases of processing times for removal methods, such as setting `innerHTML`, using `removeChild()`,`replaceChildren()` etc.

With no way to release the range objects, is there any way to remedy this slow down of node removal? Or am I better suited opening an issue report for Chromium?

Edit: Upon further testing, I discovered that the removal is in fact not slowed down much by assigning a node to a region, but by assigning that region to a [Highlight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Custom_Highlight_API) instance. I have edited the code example to reflect the highlight addition, however it is worth noting StackOverflow's snippets don't seem to support the Highlight API yet and the example needs to be manually tested.

```js
// Create test nodes
let html = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
  html += "<p>Test paragraph</p>";
}

document.body.innerHTML += html;

// Initialize the custom highlight.
let highlight = new Highlight();
CSS.highlights.set("test", highlight);

// Attach ranges
for (const paragraph of document.querySelectorAll("p")) {
  let range = new Range();
  range.setStart(paragraph.childNodes[0], 0);
  range.setEnd(paragraph.childNodes[0], 2);
  highlight.add(range);
}

// Log the performance result of trying to delete nodes after attaching a range

document.querySelector("button").onclick = () => {
  console.log("beginning delete...");
  console.time("perftest");
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
  console.timeEnd("perftest");
};
```

```css
::highlight(test) {
  background-color: #FEE6B1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me to delete</button>
```

Comment: I would suspect they are being detached, but the GC just hasn't come by yet by the time you remove the objects, which would create a bit of a pile-up. Perhaps its better to test with something like a `FinalisationEntry` to see if your `Range` is actually still active or if the GC cleans them up and when it does so?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the ranges from the highlight, before you "delete"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Highlight/clear

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I did try the `clear()` method, as well as `CSS.highlights.clear()`. It seems that the highlights and/or ranges are still attached even after clearing and thus have no effect on the performance.